# Langchain | A token error occurs when prompting. How can I resolve it?

Tags: langchain

I divided the text file into chunks and saved them in vector.

After changing the hwp to a txt file, I would like to request translation by prompting llm for the changed txt file.

However, an error occurred because the token was exceeded.

Is there a way to solve this?

(hwp is a document-like file used in Korea.)

RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'Request too large for gpt-4 in organization on tokens per min (TPM): Limit 10000, Requested 23007. The input or output tokens must be reduced in order to run successfully. Visit https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits to learn more.', 'type': 'tokens', 'param': None, 'code': 'rate_limit_exceeded'}}

```
loader = DirectoryLoader('./hwp_to_txt', glob="*.txt", loader_cls=TextLoader)
txt = loader.load()
len(txt)

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
hwp_to_txt = text_splitter.split_documents(txt)
len(hwp_to_txt)

persist_directory = "./converted_db"
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
    documents =hwp_to_txt,
    embedding=embedding,
    persist_directory=persist_directory
)

chain = ChatVectorDBChain.from_llm(llm, vectordb, return_source_documents=True)
query = f"{hwp_to_txt}to English "
result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": []})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got such exception is simple: You're using the OpenAI embedding API and the request body is too large for the limited API.
Maybe you can debug inside the python lib and found out the root API you are calling and also can know the parameter source
I guess decreasing the chunk size will be helpful.

Comment: Can you give me some example code? I'm such a newbie